# launch app after installation, there're differenct behaviors (android)

Tags: android, launcher, packageinstaller

I have a app and it has 2 activities.

```
<activity android:name=".LauncherActivity"
          android:theme="@style/LauncherTheme"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name="MainActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTop"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

1.(I expected)
Install app through command line (adb install -r app).
Tap app icon to open it, LauncherActivity shows, then I startActivity to MainActivity, MainActivity shows.
Tap HOME, then tap app icon again, MainActivity shows again.

2.(exception?)
Install app through packageinstaller. 
When finish installation, tap "Open" button in packageinstaller, LauncherActivity shows, then I startActivity to MainActivity, MainActivity shows.
Tap HOME, then tap app icon again, LauncherActivity shows again!!

In my LauncherActivity

```
private void startMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

I look into the souce, packageinstaller start activity with mLaunchIntent

InstallAppProgress.java

```
mLaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(mAppInfo.packageName);
```

ApplicationPackageManager.java

```
@Override
public Intent getLaunchIntentForPackage(String packageName) {
    // First see if the package has an INFO activity; the existence of
    // such an activity is implied to be the desired front-door for the
    // overall package (such as if it has multiple launcher entries).
    Intent intentToResolve = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intentToResolve.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_INFO);
    intentToResolve.setPackage(packageName);
    List<ResolveInfo> ris = queryIntentActivities(intentToResolve, 0);

    // Otherwise, try to find a main launcher activity.
    if (ris == null || ris.size() <= 0) {
        // reuse the intent instance
        intentToResolve.removeCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_INFO);
        intentToResolve.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intentToResolve.setPackage(packageName);
        ris = queryIntentActivities(intentToResolve, 0);
    }
    if (ris == null || ris.size() <= 0) {
        return null;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(intentToResolve);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setClassName(ris.get(0).activityInfo.packageName, ris.get(0).activityInfo.name);
    return intent;
}
```

I have no info activity, so the intent is:

```
Intent intentToResolve = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intentToResolve.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intentToResolve.setPackage(packageName);
```

I'm confused. Why there're difference behaviors? Help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still an issue for you, but I resolved this by including this in my MainActivity:

```
if (!isTaskRoot()) {
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

This is because different intents are fired depending on how the app is launched (Open via install screen vs open vs launcher).

Comment: thanks it fix my issue, launcher activity called when returning from home only happen when app launched after installation. I add this to the onCreate of my launcher activity